# Converting UI selected field to solidity smart contract

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity

Folks

While pitching the idea of smart contract to handle business processes, one of our client asked a very important question.

**Question: What if we need a different logic/business process in future? Can we have user configurable smart contract?**

Explanation: Let us say the entire logic changes due to business process change. In that case client will have to contact a solidity developer time and again whenever there is change in the process.

Our idea is to give a UI (with drag and drop option) where user can set smart contract logic and that logic will be translated into solidity smart contract.

My question is that "**Is this approach feasible**?"

If

> yes

then what are the libraries/dependencies available to do this.
If

> no

then what option do we have? What should be our approach to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like the idea. There is long way ahead to have CMS like frameworks for writing a smart contract. I think it's not feasible now. But you can find some projects that trying to do so. See this [article](https://medium.com/pennblockchain/the-case-for-graphical-smart-contract-editors-8e721cdcde93) and this [project](https://etherscripter.com/0-5-1/).